# In Scarface, why does Al Pacino say "ju" instead of "you"?

Tags: scarface

Is this something people in Cuba do when they speak English?

Comment: Could you add a link to a snippet video?

Comment: I think this question would be better asked on https://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

It is stereotypical of Cubans to speak like this, many South Americans as well so Al Pacino is going with the stereotype.

Comment: Ah-ha, I've noticed SOME native Spanish speakers make a slight noise at the start of "you" that e.g. we British don't. It's more of a whisper, bit of "hh" noise. Could it be that Al Pacino hears that same noise as a harsher 'J'??

Comment: @minisaurus its possible, i'm not sure